# SQL Server - How to use grouping sets with duplicate null columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

Reading through the 70-461 training kit, and on page 155 the example of grouping sets shows the following query

```
Select shipperid, year(shipdate), count(*)
from sales.orders
group by grouping sets 
(
    (shipperid,YEAR(shipdate)),
    (shipperid),
    (year(shipdate))
    ()
)
```

this returns a data set that includes the following two rows:

```
shipperid  shipyear  numorders
NULL       NULL      21
(...)
NULL       NULL      830
```

I understand why this happens (because of the different sets defined for the query), but would like to know how this could be used when the two values have nothing to distinguish them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is, you wouldn't be able to distinguish them, however page 158 goes on to explain the use of the GROUPING_ID function which can be used to distinguish the groups.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510624.aspx